# Доступ к ресурсам из обычного класса

Tags: android

Есть обычный класс, который не наследуется от `AppCompatActivity`. Можно ли в нем получить доступ к ресурсам приложения? Например к папке `drawable`?

```
public class MySingleton extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static MySingleton mInstance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mInstance = this;
    }

    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

}
```

Все равно получаю ошибку

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'android.content.res.Resources myApp.utils.MySingleton.getResources()'
>   on a null object reference

В другом классе в строчке

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MySingleton.getInstance().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_favorite);
```

Comment: Да, можно. Вам нужен для этого контекст. Чтобы его получить можно воспользоваться паттерном `Singleton` - т.е. глобальной статической переменной, содержащей экземпляр класса `Application`

Comment: Это что-то типа того то что я в вопрос добавила или как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: Да, что-то в этом роде) Надо только этот класс ещё в манифесте прописать в тэг `application` и убрать приватный конструктор, т.к. он может помешать системе создавать экземпляр этого класса.

Comment: Все равно получаю ошибку в другом классе java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference. А получаю Bitmap так Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(MySingleton.getInstance().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_favorite); Что не так с моим кодом?

Comment: Ох, да, надо переопределить `onCreate()` метод в вашем классе и в нём назначить `mInstance = this`  и убрать `if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton();
        }` из геттера.

Comment: все равно не помогло.

Comment: Наследоваться надо от application, не от активити

Comment: Пробовала так тоже все равно ошибка

Comment: Других идей нет. Всё описанное использовал у себя не раз - работало. Проверьте ещё раз, что наследуетесь от Application, в манифесте этот класс прописан и что у вас есть таки картинка и она в нужной папке.

Answer (score 4):

Java уже поздабыл, но что-то типо того:

Создаем класс наследуясь от `android.app.Application`:

```
public class App extends Application {
   private static App instance;
   public static App get() { return instance; }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      instance = this;
   }
}
```

Затем идем в `Manifest` и в теге `<application>` добавляем

```
android:name=".App"
```

В нужном Вам классе создаем объект `Bitmap` :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(App.get().getResources(), R.drawable.ic_favorite);
```