# Как получить строковый ресурс из класса?

Tags: android, kotlin

Хочу сделать локализацию, для этого нужно достать текст из ресурсов. Но как это сделать внутри класса без context'а?

```
enum class Tab(val id: Int, val title: String) {
    TODAY(0, "Today"), ALL(1, "All time");

    companion object {
        fun getById(id: Int) = values().first { v -> v.id == id }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашел [решение здесь (для Java)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/973146/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0)

Создаем класс наследуясь от android.app.Application:

```
public class App extends Application {
   private static App instance;
   public static App get() { return instance; }

   @Override
   public void onCreate() {
      super.onCreate();
      instance = this;
   }
}
```

Затем идем в Manifest и в теге  добавляем

```
android:name=".App"
```

В нужном классе перед `getString()` ставим `App.get()`:

```
App.get().getString()
```

Для Kotlin можно так (в App):

```
companion object {
        lateinit var instance: App
            private set
}

override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        instance = this
}
```

И потом в нужном месте:

```
App.instance.getString(R.string.Today)
```